# Creating a Friendship-system database-schema, how to?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, database-schema

I'm creating a social system, and I need to create a friendship. Can any body help me please to create it's database-schema? I want to be able to assign friends in groups (like google+) and set posts visibility based on groups or friends both (google+). Thanks to any help and suggestion.

---

I'm using **C#** and **ASP.NET MVC 3** via **Razor** and **SqlServer 2008 R2**

Answer (score 2):

First, you probably should post what you have tried.  You will get better responses with a "Help me finish this" question than with a "Please do all this work for me" question.

Basic schema could be something like:

- Users (userid, name, etc etc etc)
- UsersGroups  (userid, groupid, description, etc)
- UsersGroupsRel (userid, groupid, related userid)

That's all you should need for friends and groups.  This does require that each friend be in a group, but it doesn't prevent them from being in multiple groups.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but the issue is that I don't know where should to begin ): I have no any idea or experience. Is there any article to start please?